# How to unpack the TEDS ConRes type?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

In a TEDS (Transducer Electronic Data Sheet) Template, there are two data types described as

> ConRes.
> "Constant resolution. This is a custom data type for compressed
> floating point values that provides a linear mapping of a defined
> interval"

and

> ConRelRes.
> "Constant relative resolution. This is a custom data type for
> compressed floating point values that provides a logarithmic mapping
> of a defined interval".

As I understand they compress the range between min/max values and only use the minimum bits necessarily to encode the range.

How do I convert such value to the C type double if I know the min/max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple. For example:

```
%PhaseCorrection Phase Correction @ ref CAL 6bits ConRes (-3.2 to 3.0, step 0.1)
```

-3.2 to 3.0 is 6.2. You need `6.2/.1 + 1 = 63` discrete values. It is encoded in 6bits which can represent 64 values.

```
unsigned ConRes6bitIntegerVal = something;
double PhaseCorrection = -3.2 + 0.1 * ConRes6bitIntegerVal;
```

Comment: So for example in v0.9 template 1; `"Phase correction @ F ref",  "RO", 6, "ConRes", -3.2, 0.1, "0.0", "°"` -3.2 is the min range and 0.1 is the step. So my value would be -3.2+0.1*value. The max range is not stated more than the value is 6bits, so max is 2^6-3.2 = 60.8. Correct?